# transform C# SQL to SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Hello I have the following on my C# Code:

```
if (Combos.Count > 0)
                cmd.CommandText += "       " + (Skus.Count > 0 ? "AND" : "") + getValues("VENTAS1.Cod_Combo", (ModelObject[])Combos.ToArray());
```

Is this the correct transformation to SQL?:

```
if (@Combos <> '')
                SET @SQL = @SQL + '       ' 
                IF(@Skus <> '')
                SET @SQL = @SQL + 'AND'
                ELSE
                SET @SQL = @SQL + ''
                SET @SQL = @SQL + ' VENTAS1.Cod_Combo IN ' + @Combos
```

Im saving everything to @SQL.
Dont worry about `Combos.Count > 0` being `Combos <> ''` as there is a function above that counts the amount of "Combos" so it will not be `COUNT(@Combos > 0)` you can safely ignore that.
I think I need some BEGIN and END but Im not 100% sure.

Best Regards,

Comment: I would use SQL profiler to see what the code is doing behind the scenes. It is not always the most efficient SQL query that gets executed, but it sure is the exact translation to SQL by the library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve it.

```
 if (@Combos <> '')
            BEGIN
                SET @SQL = @SQL + '       ' 
                    IF(@Skus <> '')
                    BEGIN
                    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'AND'
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    SET @SQL = @SQL + ''
                    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' VENTAS1.Cod_Combo IN ' + @Combos
                    END
            END
```

Thanks for the support!